# Cannot connect to postgresql from remote address

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, ufw

I'm use `ubuntu 14.04` and `postgresql 9.5`.

I have allow the port in ufw, and setting configure files in postgresql. But I also cannot connect with it.

If I try to use `telnet` to my server at port 5432, it also connected timeout.

ufw setting:
    ➜  ~ ufw status
    Status: active

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
5432                       ALLOW       Anywhere
8000                       ALLOW       Anywhere
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
5432 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
8000 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

pg_hba:

```
local   all             postgres                                peer
host    all             all             all                     md5
```

postgresql.conf

```
listen_addresses = '*'
port = 5432
```

Comment: it looks like broken pg_hba.conf - missing IP mask

Comment: @PavelStehule I have tried it. But nothing is changed. The same configure can be run on my other Centos system. but now is Ubuntu.

Comment: Did you check a firewall

Comment: @PavelStehule yes, I have known the reason. my vps provider closed all ports except 22 and 80

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have known the reason.
My VPS provider close all port except 22 and 80